# Shell Scripting for pattern recognition

Tags: shell

I have got a sample file containing following string. I need to have all the strings between 'if' and 'endif' in a single line by removing new lines (\n)
Sample is shown below. I needed this output using sed or in bash script.
Can anyone help me??

--sample String

```
if
ABC
BCD
DEF
endif
if 
123
456
789
endif
```

--needed ouptput

```
ifABCBCDDEFendif

if123456789endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file contains *only* if-endif blocks:

```
awk '{ printf("%s", $0) } /^endif$/ { printf("\n") }'
```

With intervening text that should be unaltered, a slightly more complex approach is called for:

```
awk '/^if$/    { InIf = 1 } 
     /^endif$/ { InIf = 0 } 
               { printf("%s", $0) } 
     !InIf     { printf("\n") }'
```

Comment: Hello Michael, this brings all the if blocks as well into one line, but i need to have Ifendif blocks separately as shown above.

Comment: @HungryProgrammer Sorry, not sure I follow. The awk script puts each ifendif block on its own line.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose You have file tt1 which contains above string then use

```
cat tt1 | sed  's/\n//g' | sed  's/endif/endif\n/g'
```

Comment: Here is the output ifABCBCDDEFendif
if123456789endif

Answer (score 0):

A one liner will do this

If your file is file.txt then

## Command

```
cat file.txt | tr -d "\n" | sed 's@endif@endif\n@g'
```